# Amon and Moav today

Tags: halacha, history, gentiles, marriage, genealogy

The Halacha is that a Jewish woman may not marry a convert of Amon and Moav. Is there any way to know who is a descendant of Amon and Moav today?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the nations were mixed up in the days of Sennacherib the Assyrian.

[The Rambam writes](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Chapter-Twelve.htm#footnoteRef60a960660)

> When Sannecherib, King of Assyria, arose, he confused the identity of all the nations, mixing them together, and exiling them from their place. The Egyptians that live in the land of Egypt at present are of other nationalities. This also applies with regard to the Edomites in the field of Edom.
>
> Since these four forbidden nations became intermingled with all the nations of the world [with] whom it is permitted [to marry once they convert], all [converts] are permitted. For when anyone of them separates himself [from them by] converting, we operate under the presumption that he became separate from the majority. Therefore in the present age, in all places, whenever a convert converts, whether he be an Edomite, an Egyptian, an Ammonite, a Moabite, a Kushite, or from any of the other nations, whether male or female, he or she is permitted to marry among the Jewish people immediately.

This Rambam is based off the gemorah in [Berachos 28a](http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=brachos&daf=28a)

Interestingly, many poskim today don't allow DNA to have true halachic standing.

Comment: Translation note: Rambam didn't say "discriminated-against peoples", he said "prohibited peoples." Also the last sentence should read "whether Edomite, Egyptian, Ammonite, Moabite, Kushite, or any other people" (I assume the Rambam is saying not to guess true ancestry by race, which is scientifically correct).

Comment: Clarify: "the majority of the world's non-Jewish population is not prohibited [after converting], so now that the minority [Egypt Edom Amon Moab] mixed into them, we assume any individual comes from the majority population and is permitted."

Comment: I'm really not sure what DNA has to do with this. One question is using DNA evidence as proof of death; another is questions of paternity (but even if Joe Jew finds his paternal DNA doesn't match his "dad" he's still not a *mamzer*, as maybe it was a non-Jew, they doesn't generate *mamzerut*). If someone shows up today and claims to be an Edomite, you'd have to show that his father's father's father's father ... (it's patrilineal) was a pre-Sennacherib Edomite. That's only feasible in sci-fi, to the very best of my knowledge.

Comment: Nobody is currently willing to declare a person a cohen or not a cohen based on their dna.  In theory, you could find the graves of edomites, look at the DNA and find ways of discovering who is a descendant and who is not based on the Y chromosone (which only comes from the father). But nobody wants to do that.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask this as a separate question, but it directly affects the value of this answer to the present question, so I'll ask it here instead: What does the _Rambam_ do with [the _g'mara_ in _M'gila_ that says](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=12b&format=text) that _Moav_ (see _Tosafos_) was __not__ moved around by _Ashur_ (or anyone else who came along, at least until the _Purim_ story occurred)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The Gemorah in Brachos 28a says that Sennacherib displaced ALL the nations.  The gemorah in Megliah doesn't refute this, as the sages during purim said both Ammon and Moab.  It's a question on Tosefot, or perhaps one's understanding of tosofot, not so much on the Rambam. Tosofot is specifically saying that the gemorah shouldn't use the word Amon with Moav, but apparently the Rambam thought the text was correct.

Comment: Also note that Tosofot was written after Rambam died, so your question might be the other way around.

Comment: @Avi, Cohen DNA can't prove you're a Cohen, maybe your great-grandfather was a Cohen but married a divorcee, no way DNA can find that out. What if someone thought they were a Cohen but now DNA says they're not ... see the end of Ediyot, no worse than Eliyahu Hanavi. What you're talking about with DNA from 2500+ year old graves is sci-fi.

Comment: @avi, the _g'mara_ there says both _Amon_ and _Moav_ did not get moved around by _Ashur_. (_Tosafos_ restrict it to just _Moav_. Ignoring _Tosafos_ makes the question even stronger against the _Rambam_.)

Comment: @Shalom, I'm not sure why you think old dna is sci-fi, look up the genographic program.  @msh210 I think you are reading the gemorah incorrectly.  Tosofot is trying to reconcile the gemora in brachot with the gemorah in Megilah, limiting the midrash to only Moav. Tosofot claims that the word Ammon should not be there, to fix a perceived contradiction between the gemorah in Berachot which discusses a convert from Ammon, and the gemorah in Megliah, which sites a midrash of what the rabbis said in the times of Mordechai. When midrash and halacha conflict, we side with halacha.

Comment: @avi, very well, but even limiting _M'gila_ to _Moav_ results in a question on the _Rambam_. (Incidentally, I didn't get notification due to your use of "@msh210", as you'd already typed "@Shalom" in the same post and only the first such counts.)

Comment: I changed the quote to one that was more textually accurate and less racist. See here http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5112n.htm  The writer of that translation clearly had an agenda and changed the translation to fit his agenda. I hope I didn't overstep my bounds.

Comment: @msh210 I think ibts a good seperate question. I'm not sure how the Gemorah in Brachot can say that all the nations were mixed up, when the gemorah in M'gilah says that moav and amnon were undisturbed.  Tosofet's attempt to say the text is wrong, doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: I believe many Rishonim and Achronim argue on the Rambam and forbid Egyptians even today because Sancheriv never mixed them up. See SA EH 4:10

Comment: Odd, Egyptians today are known not to be the Egyptians of old. They are mostly Arabs now because of the Caliphate.